# How to put sprites in binary file in the same way as DirectX Example "Foxbear"?

Tags: c, binary, directx, sprite

I started to learn an example with 2d graphics in the old DirectX SDK and ran into a problem. The fact is that sprites in the example game "foxbear" are loaded from a binary file (all 287 sprites on this binary file). if open a binary file "foxbear.art" you can see name of BMP files start from offset 00000000 to offset 00001300 ("001.bmp", "002.bmp"...), then in offset 00001324 started BMP images.

My question is, how create the same binary file?
Where in the beginning of binary are the names ("001.bmp, "002.bmp"...) of the sprites and then the sprites themselves.

[screenshot of binary file foxbear.art](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D1yC.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnJRp.png)

Comment: That's a *really old* DirectX SDK. There are more modern solutions for generating 'sprite sheets' which are far more efficient than individual images for each sprite. See [SpriteSheet](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SpriteSheet) topic in the *DirectX Tool Kit* which shows how to use it with ``SpriteBatch``.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer, but modern solution does won't suit me. Because i programming for old console (console only understand directx 6.1).

Comment: OK. Not aware of any console that used DirectX 6.1.